# Why can't ld find library from path in /etc/ld.so.conf?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

I want to add the `/opt/vertica/lib64` into system library paths, so I do the following steps:
(1) Add the `/opt/vertica/lib64` into`/etc/ld.so.conf`, and run `ldconfig`,
(2) Check it:

```
 bash# ldconfig -p | grep vertica
    libverticaodbc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
    ......
```

But when I run "`ld -lverticaodbc --verbose`" command:

```
==================================================
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libverticaodbc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libverticaodbc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libverticaodbc.a failed
ld: cannot find -lverticaodbc
```

The `ld` doesn't find `verticaodbc` from `/opt/vertica/lib64`.

Could anyone give some clues? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld` is the *static* [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29). `ld.so` is the [*dynamic* linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (and `ldconfig` &  `ldd` are related to the dynamic linker).

You need to add `-L/opt/vertica/lib64/` to your `ld` arguments at *link* time (and you usually should link with `gcc` or `g++`). Practically speaking, this means editing your build infrastructure -e.g. your `Makefile` - to add a few dozen characters.

See [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)

Read also [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) & [Levine's book: *Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Comment: Is there any method not use "`-L/opt/vertica/lib64/`" explicitly? Except adding into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: No, but why is linking with `-L/opt/vertica/lib64/` an issue? Just edit your `Makefile` !

Comment: Just feel not an elegant way. If the library path is changed, the Makefile will also need to be modified. On Solaris, there is `crle`.

Comment: Then, improve `ld` to fit your needs. *binutils* is free software, you can improve it (as long as you obey to the GPL license)