# Confusing about the implementation of shared library in Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I'm doing some experiment about shared library in Linux. By reading several papers I think I know what happens when a shared library function is called.
But when I am trying to trace the memory to get the binary code in a shared library function, I find something strange. In my opinion, after calling a shared library function, the corresponding slot in .got.plt should contain the actual function address, but my experiment shows that it still remains the same, i.e the address of the second instruction in func@plt section. I'm rather confused about this, so if anyone could help me?
Here is my code and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned long u_l;

int main()
{    
    char *p_ch = strstr("abc", "b");
    printf("result = %s\n", p_ch);

    long long *p = (long long *) &strstr;

    printf("data = %llx\n", *(p));

    long long k = *p >> 16; 
    u_l *entry_addr = (u_l *)(k & 0x00000000ffffffff);

    printf("entry_addr = %lx\n", entry_addr);

    u_l *func_addr = (u_l *)*entry_addr;
    printf("func_addr = %lx\n", func_addr);
    printf("code = %llx\n", *func_addr);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
result = bc  
data = 680804a00c25ff  
entry_addr = 804a00c  
func_addr = 8048326  
code = 68080400000068
```

Thanks first!
PS: Please don't ask me why I need to get the code of a shared library function. Of course I know the source code and the binary could be obtained easily. It's just a experiment.
My GCC version is 4.7.3. Kernel version is 3.8.0-35

Comment: Did you read the references in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27223725/841108) (notably Drepper's paper)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The question is not about how to build a shared object library, but how they are linked dynamically in a practical implementation of the dynamic linker.

Comment: But Drepper's paper explains how the dynamic linker works....

Comment: I have just read it. It says the same in section 1.5.5 GOT and PLT as what I have seen from other papers.

Comment: Obviously, whatever the mechanism is works.  So look at the maps file to determine where the library is, and do an instruction level trace of a 2nd call, and you should see how it actually gets there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is the logic of Your program, but I'll try to show where address changes.

```
$ gcc -Wall -g test.c
$ gdb a.out
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40054c: file test.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400544 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400545 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400548 <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
=> 0x000000000040054c <+8>: movq   $0x4006fd,-0x28(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400554 <+16>:    mov    $0x400700,%eax
   0x0000000000400559 <+21>:    mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdx
   0x000000000040055d <+25>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000000400560 <+28>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400563 <+31>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400568 <+36>:    callq  0x400430 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000040056d <+41>:    movq   $0x400450,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400575 <+49>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400579 <+53>:    mov    (%rax),%rdx
   0x000000000040057c <+56>:    mov    $0x40070d,%eax
   0x0000000000400581 <+61>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000000400584 <+64>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400587 <+67>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040058c <+72>:    callq  0x400430 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400591 <+77>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400595 <+81>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x0000000000400598 <+84>:    sar    $0x10,%rax
   0x000000000040059c <+88>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
```

Let's make breakpoint in PLT table at `printf` entry (0x400430) and continue:

```
(gdb) break *0x400430
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400430
(gdb) continue 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000400430 in printf@plt ()
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function printf@plt:
=> 0x0000000000400430 <+0>: jmpq   *0x200bca(%rip)        # 0x601000 <printf@got.plt>
   0x0000000000400436 <+6>: pushq  $0x0
   0x000000000040043b <+11>:    jmpq   0x400420
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/x 0x601000
0x601000 <printf@got.plt>:  0x00400436
```

In PLT table You can see indirect jump by address stored in GOT at 0x601000 (0x200bca+0x400430+6), which at first function invocation resolves to next address in PLT (**0x00400436**: pushq and jump to dynamic linker). Dynamic linker finds real `printf`, updates it's GOT entry and jumps to it.

Next time You call the same `printf` function (and hit the breakpoint), it's entry at GOT 0x601000 is already updated to **0xf7a6d840**, so there is jump directly to `printf`, not to dynamic linker.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
result = bc

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000400430 in printf@plt ()
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function printf@plt:
=> 0x0000000000400430 <+0>: jmpq   *0x200bca(%rip)        # 0x601000 <printf@got.plt>
   0x0000000000400436 <+6>: pushq  $0x0
   0x000000000040043b <+11>:    jmpq   0x400420
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/x 0x601000
0x601000 <printf@got.plt>:  0xf7a6d840
```

This example is from 64bit Linux. On other *NIX'es assembly or similar details may vary, but idea remains the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed show. I test my program again and find another amazing thing: the slot of printf@got.plt is changed just as your show, but the function strstr still remains the same. This makes me feel rather rather confused. If strstr is not dynamically linked, why there is strstr@plt? If it is, why the slot of strstr@got.plt doesn't change? Oh my God!

Comment: One thing else, I couldn't find printf in my libc.so, whose path is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so. I tried several other functions in this file and find that they all behave the same like strstr, i,e those function's slot in gol.plt isn't changed. I believe they're dynamically linked because the function prototypes don't exist in the dumped file of my program. It's really really strange.

Comment: @Michael in Your program (as in question) call to `strstr` gets optimized (at least on my machine), so there is no call to this function at all. Do You see such call in Your dissassembly? Slots of individual functions are updated only **after first call** of particular function. Not updated entry should point to the next instruction in the PLT table, so You should be able to determine if function was already called or not. If still in trouble, please provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

> One thing else, I couldn't find printf in my libc.so, …

This program shows you an address and the containing library (using a Glibc extension) for each function given as an argument:

```
/* cc -ldl */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  while (*++argv)
  {
    void *handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle) puts(dlerror()), exit(1);
    void *p = dlsym(handle, *argv);
    char *s = dlerror();
    if (s) puts(s), exit(1);
    printf("%s = %p\n", *argv, p);
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(p, &info))
        printf("%s contains %s\n", info.dli_fname, info.dli_sname);
  }
}
```